# GCC directory option -isystem

Tags: gcc

From this link: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html

> If a standard system include
>   directory, or a directory specified
>   with -isystem, is also specified with
>   -I, the -I option will be ignored. The directory will still be searched but
>   as a system directory at its normal
>   position in the system include chain.

What is the way to run this?

```
[14:45:37 Wed Apr 27] ~/junkPrograms/src  $gcc hello.c -isystem -I ../include/
../include/: file not recognized: Is a directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
[14:45:42 Wed Apr 27] ~/junkPrograms/src  $gcc hello.c -I isystem ../include/
../include/: file not recognized: Is a directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
[14:45:57 Wed Apr 27] ~/junkPrograms/src  $
```

and does this mean that if *-isystem* is attached, the dir will be given the precedence of a normal system dir?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) says:

> -isystem dir
>
> Search dir for header files, after all directories specified by -I but before the standard system directories. Mark it as a system directory, so that it gets the same special treatment as is applied to the standard system directories. If dir begins with =, then the = will be replaced by the sysroot prefix; see --sysroot and -isysroot.

So you're using it wrong. You need to specify a directory for the -isystem option itself, it doesn't work like a "modifier" of the -I option like you seem to be trying.

I believe your command should be:

```
$ gcc -isystem ../include hello.c
```

[System headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html) get special treatment w.r.t. warnings (since they are read only, and some cannot be written in strictly conforming code)

Comment: So, how it should be? He has an example. Can you write fixed command?

Comment: what is the "special treatment" as is applied to the standard system directories?

Comment: Do you know if it matters if -isystem is before/after -I arguments?

Comment: I added a link to the system headers docs (awaiting moderation): https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html

Comment: The link in the answer is not pointing to the intended content anymore. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html might be a better read these days.