# Xcode fails to find .pch file after adding "-isystem" flag

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang

I wanted to prevent Xcode from generating tons of warnings for third-party libraries I use and added `-isystem` flag to the "Other compiler flags". However, now build fails, giving me an error that my `.pch` file can not be found.

How does one affect the other? Can't wrap my head around this one.

Comment: You need to pass `-isystem` a directory, by itself it's useless, and it will end up not finding the includes since it's not a mind reader. The correct syntax is `-isystem directory` ...

Comment: look at here:[http://stackoverflow.com/a/5801839/5575752](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5801839/5575752)