# GCC bug when using -Woverloaded-virtual flag

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

Let's take [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/K556YTvqd):

```
#include <boost/asio/impl/error.ipp>

struct Type : public boost::system::error_category
{
    const char * name() const noexcept override 
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    std::string message(int) const override
    {
        return {};
    }
};
```

As we can see, it compiles without warnings.

Now let’s create [identical code](https://godbolt.org/z/Ta7Y465Wh) (the method prototypes are copied one-to-one from the boost ones):

```
#include <string>

struct Base
{
    virtual std::string message(int) const = 0;
    virtual char const * message(int, char *, std::size_t) const noexcept
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
};


struct Deriv : Base
{
    std::string message(int) const
    {
        return {};
    }
};
```

And suddenly, the compiler starts talking about hiding the method. What is this? GCC compiler bug? Because Clang, for example, does not give a warning in this case.

Comment: Also please link to the boost sources where you copied the signatures from. Are *both* methods virtual there?

Comment: Indeed, looks like a bug that it's not reported in the first case.

Comment: Yes, both methods are virtual https://github.com/boostorg/system/blob/develop/include/boost/system/detail/error_category.hpp#L143-L144

Comment: GCC doesn't produce warnings (except maybe for #pragma warn) from headers in the system include directories.  This applies to the default system header paths, as well as those added via `-isystem`

Comment: gcc doesn't report warnings in files found in system include directories.

Comment: Where can I read about this (gcc doesn't report warnings in files found in system include directories)?

Comment: @d7d1cd in the docs, see e.g. via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801754/gcc-directory-option-isystem

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Good find, godbolt has `-isystem/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_80_0` in the compilation options when boost library is added. Though I'd still consider it a bug that warning is attached to base class with note in derived class (instead of having it the other way round).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a misinterpretation of the warning message?

If your class `Deriv` defines only one method from the overloaded ones in `Base`, all other overloads are hidden, even if they are virtual. For me the warning seems to be correct!

Simplified example:

```
struct Base 
{
    virtual void f1() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
    virtual void f1( int i) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};


struct Deriv : Base 
{
    // using Base::f1; // << add this line to get f1( int ) reachable
    void f1() override )
    {    
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }    
};

int main()
{
    Deriv d;
    d.f1();
    d.f1(1);
}
```

This simply did not only warn, it also raises an error as `f1()` can not be reached!

You simply can add all other overloads to your derived class by adding `using Base::f1;` into `Deriv`.

The given goodbolt link to fix the boost thing is here: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sYWs3Tf4n)
It can simply be fixed with adding the `using` statement.

Comment: The thing is that the first example has exactly the same issue and no warning reported by gcc.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen No! The first one has two functions with two DIFFERENT names `name` and `message`! Your second example has a SINGLE name for two functions which makes them overloaded!

Comment: `boost::system::error_category` has two `virtual` overloads of `message`: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/system/doc/html/system.html#ref_boostsystemerror_category_hpp (godbolt example with hiding, error happens if you uncomment the line in main: https://godbolt.org/z/bG3PYGKP7)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Not the code your presented here! It is quite hard to find problems if the problem is given in some links but not in the code shown here! Sorry! Fix your post or delete it!

Comment: I'm not the OP.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, sorry, but quite clear that the above presented code is not describing the problem! Vote to close!

Comment: The first code example requires the boost library. I couldn’t provide the entire boost code just so that you could reproduce the error without unnecessary movements.

Comment: @d7d1cd: You simply have the same issue in your boost example. See godbolt link please. Simply add the using statement and try to understand the simplified code. You have an overload set of virtual functions, derive from that class, only override one and all the others are hidden. That is simply an error :-)

Comment: @Klaus The question is not why gcc emits the warning, or how to fix it. The question is why gcc *does not* emit the warning given seemingly identical code.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: Both, the code with the boost as with the simplified code of mine reproduce the SAME warnings and errors on my system. I use gcc 13.2.1. I simply can't reproduce any difference.

Comment: @Klaus I can on mine. Perhaps your install of boost doesn't sit under /usr/include.